# Find div before button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying addClass to `wizard-step` when button clicked, but still no luck :/

```
 <div class="mt-4">
    <div class="wizard-steps">
      <div class="wizard-step">
        <div class="wizard-step-icon">
          <i class="far fa-user"></i>
       </div>
    </div>

    <form class="wizard-content mt-2" id="regForm">
    <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 text-right">
            <button type="button" onclick="step0(this);" class="btn">Next</button>
        </div>
     </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
 function step0(element) {
  $(element).prev('div').find('.wizard-step').addClass('wizard-step-active');
      }
</script>
```

Can anyone please help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prev` is used to retrieve a previous sibling element. The `.wizard-step` you want to target is a child of a sibling to a parent of the button being clicked. As such you need to use `closest()` instead.

Also note that `onclick` (and all the other `onX` attributes) are not good practice and should be avoided. As you're already using jQuery you can attach your event unobtrusively, like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.wizard-steps').find('.wizard-step').addClass('wizard-step-active');
  });
});
```

```css
.wizard-step-active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mt-4">
  <div class="wizard-steps">
    <div class="wizard-step">
      <div class="wizard-step-icon">
        <i class="far fa-user">User icon</i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form class="wizard-content mt-2" id="regForm">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 text-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Alternatively, instead of calling `find()` from the shared parent, you could select the `form` and use `prev()`:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.wizard-content').prev('.wizard-step').addClass('wizard-step-active');
});
```

Either is fine, it just depends on how your HTML is structured as to which fits best for this use case.

Comment: thanks Rory but still no luck , its not adding class.

Comment: in your HTML form is inside wizard-steps , but its not form is outside of wizard-steps

Comment: The HTML is copied directly from your question

Comment: i used Inspect Element :) never mind thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the div immediately before the button, but the one containing the relevant item(s). So instead of `$(element).prev('div')` write `$('.mt-4')`.

Answer (score 0):

Your this parameter is referring your button, not your div.

You can do this without Jquery, just using your function like this:

```
function step0() {
  const element = document.getElementsByClassName('wizard-step');
  element.classList.add('wizard-step-active');
}
```

So, you don't need to pass this as a parameter to step0 function.

Comment: I think the point here is that the OP wants to traverse the DOM from the button to the target div as this HTML will be repeated throughout the page